# attempting to run an if statement within a for loop but keep getting ERROR 9 Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

im new to writing code so i know this is probably something stupid and easy but every time i try to run the program it comes up with error 9 ( subscript out of range ). im not sure as to what it causing this.

[image]

```
Dim i As Integer


Sub DepotsDue()
   For i = 1 To 150

     If Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells(B, 2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(E, 1 + i).Value Then
     Worksheets("Depots Due").Cells(A, 5 + i).Value = Worksheets("Weekly").Cells(A, 2 + i).Value
     End If

   Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: oh ffs ahah, thanks. however, ive changed it to this (code below) and it still says same error.

Comment: Sub DepotsDue()
   For i = 1 To 150
 
     If Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells(2, "B").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1 + i, "E").Value Then
     Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells(5 + i, "A").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2 + i, "A").Value
     End If
  
   Next i
     
End Sub

Comment: im not sure whether im referencing the worksheets incorrectly maybe.

Comment: hmmm, ive attached a picture of what my worksheets are named in the question. am i referencing them properly?  For example, i'm not sure whether it should be referenced as Worksheets("Sheet2") or Worksheets("Weekly")

Comment: Reference the name. So, `Weekly` & `Monthly`. Also, move your `Dim i as Integer` inside your sub and change it to `Dim i as Long`

Comment: works perfect now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your `Cells` syntax is wrong. Here are 3 equivalent ways to reference your second cell in your code *(`Sheet2 E[i + 1]`)*

---

```
Cells(row index, column index) = Cells(1 + i, 5)
Cells(row index, column letter) = Cells(1 + i, "E")
```

You can also use `Range` like so

```
Range("E" & 1 + i)
```